# npm installs getting stuck

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I am trying to install some npm packages (the mysql package in this case) and it randomly gets stuck upon installing.

Output:

```
119 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream' -> 'C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\.readable-stream.DELETE'
120 verbose cwd C:\Projects\Vextoria
121 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
122 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
123 verbose node v12.16.2
124 verbose npm  v6.14.4
125 error code ENOENT
126 error syscall rename
127 error path C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream
128 error dest C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\.readable-stream.DELETE
129 error errno -4058
130 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream' -> 'C:\Projects\Vextoria\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\.readable-stream.DELETE'
131 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
132 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting package-json and then installing mysql using npm.  This worked for me in the past

Comment: It just gets stuck again.

Comment: strange, and I'm assuming you already tried creating an entire new project using npm init?

Comment: I believe it might be related to the mysql package, but I am not sure. It worked perfectly until a few minutes ago when I edited the package.json file in a complete different project.

Comment: do you have the older version of it to compare side by side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` then.

If that doesn't work you can uninstall the package (`npm un <packagename>`), remove the `node_modules` folder and install it again `npm i <packagename>`